# How do I store values from a method parameter into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, methods

I am writing a program to store certain Recipe info. into an array. Using method RecipeEntry(), with its parameters, the program is meant to store up to a maximum of 3 recipes into an array named: totalEntry[].

Below is my attempt at writing this program, however, I am getting errors .. unable to figure out what it is that I am missing.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RecipeArray
{
    private String author;
    private Recipe recpH_1;
    private Recipe recpC_2;

  private static RecipeEntry[] totalEntry = new RecipeEntry[3];
  private static int entryCount;

  public RecipeArray(String author, Recipe hot, Recipe cold)  // constructor
  {
    entryCount = 0;
    this.author = author;
    recpH_1 = hot;
    recpC_2 = cold;
    totalEntry[entryCount] = new RecipeArray(author, recpH_1, recpC_2);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    RecipeEntry("Mary Bush", SpaghettiHOT, SpaghettiCOLD);
    // RecipeEntry method, when called should pass its parameter values into 
    // totalEntry [] array.  entryCount variable should keep count of every entry.
    System.out.println("ALL ENTRY =   " + entryCount + Arrays.toString(totalEntry)); 
  }
}
```

```
public class Recipe   //create class data of type recipe
{
  private String name;
  private int id, rating;

  public Recipe(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
    id = 0;
    rating = 0;
  }
}
```

**The expected output should print a list of the entries - Example:**
**Output:**

index 0 - [Mary Bush, SpaghettiHOT{id=0, rating=0}, SpaghettiCOLD{id=0, rating=0}]

Comment: Perhaps read those error messages. You certainly can not `return` an array (or any value) from a constructor, just to guess one of them.

Comment: @tevemadar I have removed the return line.... mistake acknowledged, however, calling the method, I still expected the values send in the parameters to be passed into and stored in the array: totalEntry[] - specifically at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't catch the returned Array from your method:
RecipeEntry("Mary Bush", SpaghettiHOT, SpaghettiCOLD);

Actually the RecipeArray as you wrote will return an Array; it means that the method will pass and Array to it's caller.
Changing the mentioned line with the following line will solve the problem:
RecipeEntry[] totalEntry = RecipeEntry("Mary Bush", SpaghettiHOT, SpaghettiCOLD);

Visit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/importance-of-return-type-in-java for better understanding of Java Methods: